# NPE for org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.removeSemicolonContentInternal Spring 5.1.10 RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi we are facing the below error sporadically for our data rest api;s in production . This issues is coming from spring 5.1.10 Release . AS this is sporadic its bit difficult to reproduce locally . Is there anyone from spring aware if this has been fixed already and can work via an upgrade ?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.removeSemicolonContentInternal(UrlPathHelper.java:511)
at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.removeSemicolonContent(UrlPathHelper.java:507)
at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.decodeAndCleanUriString(UrlPathHelper.java:440)
at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getRequestUri(UrlPathHelper.java:329)
at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication(UrlPathHelper.java:245)
at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getPathWithinServletMapping(UrlPathHelper.java:196)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromServletMapping(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.java:95)
at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.UriComponentsBuilderFactory.createBuilderFromRequest(UriComponentsBuilderFactory.java:67)
at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.UriComponentsBuilderFactory.getBuilder(UriComponentsBuilderFactory.java:61)
at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.java:141)
at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilder.java:182)
```

From the looks of it looks that requestUri is null not sure possibly coming from

```
public String getRequestUri(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String uri = (String) request.getAttribute(WebUtils.INCLUDE_REQUEST_URI_ATTRIBUTE);
    if (uri == null) {
        uri = request.getRequestURI();
    }
    return decodeAndCleanUriString(request, uri);
}
```